# Is it possible to crawl directly through a site tree a site tree remotely or locally?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, url, tree, web-crawler

I'm a n00b to web development and I have a n00b question.

Suppose there's a site that is, for example, something like

```
index.php
    page1.php
    page2.php
      page2-1.php
      page2-2.php
    page3.php
```

Is there a way I can try to go directly to every subpage starting from the index, without any knowledge of the subpage names? In concrete terms, is it possible in, say, Javascript, to construct a `function` that works like

```
console.log(printSiteTree("StackOverflow.com");
/* Prints: 

   stackoverflow.com
     stackoverflow.com/questions
            .
            .
            .
            stackoverflow.com/questions/29633992
            .
            .
            .
                stackoverflow.com/questions/29633992/is-there-any-tool-to-calculate-the-distance-between-a-program-point-and-a-execut
            .
            .
            .
     stackoverflow.com/tags
     .
     .
     .
*/
```

without relying on any undue brute force?

Comment: You'd have to interpret the content of the initial page, find URLs there, and repeat with those pages etc.

Comment: if the pages are linked then it's easy. if they are not linked, it takes a LOT of guessing.

Comment: @Pointy I understand that's a way to do it, but is that the only way other than brute force of guessing trillions of possible subpage names?

Comment: Where do you suppose the information to do something like that might come from? Does any website you're familiar with publish a complete map of available URLs?

Comment: you can get a dir listing from the server and give that to JS so it knows where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Theory

You can get the list of the links on the site, if the site wants to let you have them.
This is done via a site map: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_map

Usually, a site provides the location of the sitemap in its robots.txt file, so that the crawlers can access it.
Most likely it will be an XML file with URL's nested under `sitemap/loc`.

### Example

Let's say we want to get links to crawl http://www.msn.com/.
We can go to the usual robots file location, which is: http://www.msn.com/robots.txt and there we can find the line:
`Sitemap: http://sitemap.msn.com/xml`
so we visit the URL and we get our URL list:

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
<loc>http://sitemap.msn.com/xml/en-nz-autos-0</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>http://sitemap.msn.com/xml/en-nz-entertainment-0</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>http://sitemap.msn.com/xml/en-nz-entertainment-1</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>http://sitemap.msn.com/xml/en-nz-finance-0</loc>
</sitemap>
```

### Disclaimer

Not all sites will give you this, and there is no guarantee what links will be there or that it will be a complete list. It's for you to figure out if it's useful to your purpose.